# Quitar comillas de la salida de una lista

Tags: python

me gustaría presentar un problema que me a surgido con las salidas de una lista en python, el caso es que estoy haciendo un programa que recorre los directorios de un pc, al conseguir la primera lista de directorios (La que se consigue desde el primer directorio de trabajo) tiene que acceder a las listas encontradas en ese directorio, y en ese punto es donde falla:

```
import os
import ftplib
carpetas = []
actuals = os.getcwd()
print actuals
def paso1 ():
    lista = os.listdir(".")
    for x in lista:
        if os.path.isdir(x) == True:
            num = lista.index(x)
            carpetas.append(lista[num])
paso1()

def paso2():
    for i in carpetas:
        os.chdir(i)
        direct = str(os.getcwd())
        directorios = {direct : ""}
        lista = os.listdir(".")
        for x in lista:
            if os.path.isdir(x) == True:
                num = lista.index(x)
                directorios[direct].append(lista[num])
        os.chdir("..")
```

paso2()

Cuando intento acceder al siguiente directorio en "os.chdir(i)" da error, ya que "i" se presenta con comillas, como las salidas de una lista.

¿Se les ocurre alguna manera de que la salida sea sin comillas?

El error:

```
/home/angrymasther/Escritorio
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Servidor2.py", line 28, in <module>
paso2()
File "Servidor2.py", line 17, in paso2
os.chdir(i)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Web'
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es posible que el error que tienes no tenga nada que ver con las comillas. Pero es difícil saberlo pues el código que has puesto es incompleto. Si pones un programa completo que sea posible ejecutar será más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: El OP comenta : "Cuando intento acceder al siguiente directorio en "os.chdir(i)" da error, ya que "i" se presenta con comillas, como las salidas de una lista. "

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy confusa, la función `os.chdir` tiene como parámetro de entrada válido la ruta pasada como una cadena (con comillas simples, dobles o triples eso en Python en este caso da igual). Es decir, una llamada normal sería algo como: `os.chdir("/usr/tmp")`. Lo primero que necesitamos saber es el error que te retorna al completo y por otro lado saber que es `carpetas` (se supone que una lista), que tipo de dato contiene y como obtienes esa lista.

Comment: Dices ' "i" se presenta con comillas, como las salidas de una lista', pero una lista no es una función, no retorna nada, una lista puede almacenar cualquier objeto desde una cadena, un entero hasta una función o una instancia de clase). Deberias ampliar la pregunta con todo tu código y el error para poder reproducir el problema. Mirate [mcve]

Comment: Revisa el código que has puesto, por favor. El código de error que das indica que paso2 está llamándose a si misma recursivamente. Y en python la identación es muy importante; se te ha quedado esa llamada recursiva fuera del bloque del código. También estaría bien poner un comentario en el código indicando cuales son las líneas 28 y 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

antes de hace el `os.chdir(i)`, intenta hacerle un replace de caracteres

algo asi

```
i.replace('"', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Podría ser un replace de los elementos en la lista, pero además de comilla doble también remueva comilla sencilla:

```
String palabrasinQuotes = palabra.replace('"', '').replace("'", '')
```

ejemplo:

```
   String palabrasinQuotes = lista[num].replace('"', '').replace("'", ''))
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejecutar lo que has puesto? `directorios[direct]` en el código de la pregunta es un `str`. No le puedes aplicar `append`pues da un error : `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: Otra vez tu de nuevo, **ya te dije que no soy menor de edad**. Revisa la pregunta, el usuario tiene directorios[direct].append() **porque no le comentas esto al OP en lugar de estar hostigandome todo el tiempo.** @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Si tienes una mejor respuesta te invito como siempre a que la agregues.